# Returning a class object in java equivalent for objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, methods

I have a Java class where I'm returning the class objects using the add method. I'm trying to write an equivalent Obj-C method. Should I have to declare the objective C method as void and update the class variables inside the method?

```
 public class TesCodeRequest{

            private String apiKey;
            private String apiSecret; 
            private String endpoint;


            public TesCodeRequest(String apiKey, String apiSecret, String endpoint) {
              //initialization done here 
            }


           public TesCodeRequest add(String endpoint, Object... fields) {
             //method 
            }
}
```

Expected add method in Obj-c

```
   -(void)add:(NSString *)endPoint andObject:(NSArray *field{
    //endpoint and other variables to be updated here.

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you should declare init method with you parameter (if you parameters is private, otherwise you can assign it after standart init) and call it form add:

```
-(TesCodeRequest *)add:(NSString *)endPoint andObject:(NSArray *field{
//endpoint and other variables to be updated here.
TesCodeRequest *testCodeRequest = [[TesCodeRequest  alloc] initWithEndPoint:endPoint ...];
return testCodeRequest;
```

}

If you want call this method without create instance of TesCodeRequest, use class  method (`+(TesCodeRequest *)add:(NSString *)endPoint andObject:(NSArray *field{`)